# Cast Any to Array[String]

Tags: scala, for-loop

I am trying to convert Any to Array[String].

```
 val x="High"
 val DeviceStatus= scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[String]()
 val deviceWithstatus= if( x=="High") {  
  DeviceStatus += x +"#"+"ACTIVE" 
  DeviceStatus += x +"#"+"WORKING" 
  DeviceStatus
  }

// Error this line

val CastDeviceWithStatus= deviceWithstatus.asInstanceOf[Array[String]]

//Error
//java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String
```

I am trying to get back array[String] out of the if statement.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: No cast needed. Just add an `else` to the `if` expression. Then use `deviceWithstatus.toArray` instead of `asInstanceOf`.

Comment: Thanks @jwvh. Now I am getting error -  `value toArray is not a member of java.io.Serializable`

Comment: The `else` clause has to return _the same type_ as the `if` clause. Try `else DeviceStatus`.

Comment: Thanks again @jwvh. Its working now.